# Grouping nodes by value of grandchildren

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have an XML that has a group type as the deepest node. I have to group a subsection of the XML, but otherwise return the exact same XML.

I have looked at different questions in Stackoverflow. Specifically, I have been basing my answer on this one:
[Grouping xml nodes by value of a child in Xsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711039/grouping-xml-nodes-by-value-of-a-child-in-xsl)

The input XML looks like this:

```
<list>
    <element>
        <foo>
            <bar>
            </bar>
        </foo>
        <values>
            <position>
                <foo2>
                </foo2>
                <type>first
                </type>
            </position>
            <position>
                <foo2>
                </foo2>
                <type>second
                </type>
            </position>
            <position>
                <foo2>
                </foo2>
                <type>first
                </type>
            </position>
        </values>
    </element>    
</list>
```

The output XML should look like this:

```
<list>
    <element>
        <foo>
            <bar>
            </bar>
        </foo>
        <types>
            <first>
                <values>
                    <position>
                        <foo2>
                        </foo2>
                    </position>
                    <position>
                        <foo2>
                        </foo2>
                    </position>
                </values>
            </first>
            <second>
                <values>
                    <position>
                        <foo2>
                        </foo2>
                    </position>
                </values>
            </second>
        </types>
    </element>    
</list>
```

Up until now I have the following XLST which copies the transform on the top:

```
    <xsl:key name="types" match="type" use="."/>

    <xsl:template match="/list">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="element/values/position/type[generate-id() = generate-id(key('types', .)[1])]"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|comment()|text()"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="type">
        <xsl:variable name="currentType" select="."/>
        <xsl:element name="{$currentType}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|comment()|text()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|comment()|text()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As soon as I put an apply templates on the parent nodes (in the template that matches type), it does not return anything anymore:

```
    <xsl:template match="type">
        <xsl:variable name="currentType" select="."/>
        <xsl:element name="{$currentType}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../../*|@*|comment()|text()"/>
        </xsl:element>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing: you want to group `position` nodes by common `type` - so you should make your key match `position` and use `type`.

Once you do that, it can be simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="pos-by-type" match="position" use="type"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="values">
    <types>
        <xsl:for-each select="position[generate-id() = generate-id(key('pos-by-type', type)[1])]">
            <xsl:element name="{normalize-space(type)}">
                <values>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('pos-by-type', type)"/>
                </values>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </types>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="type"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that this depends on `type` containing a string that is a valid XML element name. In your example it isn't, and I used `normalize-space()` to make it so. But your real input may contain other string with other problems.

Comment: I was on the right way after asking this question. My problem was that in the line: <xsl:apply-templates select="key('pos-by-type', type)"/>, i was giving a relative path to the parent i.e. ../.. and it was only printing the first value. I think I still don't understand the keys concept. Thanks a lot! Is there a big performance difference between this and the Muenchian Grouping method?

Comment: @havan This **is** the Muenchian grouping method.